# Plot.ly in Timemode: fixed grid size

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a timemode chart with timestamps on the x-axis. 
The dataset is appromximately 20 seconds long and plot.ly automatically sets a tick label every 2 seconds on the x-axis, which is fine.

However, the x-axis grid lines are automatically set to the positions of the ticks.
I would like to have fix grildlines every second, independent from the x-axis timestamps/ticks.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot do that directly but you could add the grid yourself via [`shapes`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-shapes).

```js
var data =   {
    x: [],
    y: [],
    type: 'scatter'
  };
var lines = [];

//get a random time series
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) {
    data.x.push(startTime + i * 1000);
    data.y.push(i % 5 * Math.random())
}

//create a line every 1000 msecs
for (i = Math.min(...data.x); i < Math.max(...data.x); i += 1000) {
  lines.push({type: 'line',
              xref: 'x0',
              x0: i,
              x1: i,
              y0: Math.min(...data.y),
              y1: Math.max(...data.y),
              layer: 'below',
              line: {color: 'gray'}
             }
            );
}

var layout = {xaxis: {type: 'date',
                      dtick: 2000,
                      showgrid: false
                     },
              yaxis: {showgrid: false},
              shapes: lines
             };
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [data], layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```